# Fastest access to collection in PLSQL for updating values associated with a record

Tags: oracle, performance, memory, plsql

I'm trying to cache data to memory for fast access on 3 different keys in PLSQL. The problem is not really existent in any language that has pointers, but i'm struggling with PLSQL as of there is none that I'm aware of. I need to do this because I have a very large looping function that updates data in a very fine grained way and would last quite an eternity otherwise.

The basic idea is that I have a collection in memory sorted by key_1. I'd want to make changes to a value of the first record which would influence the key_1 value of the record itself and several other specific values of records in the collection which have the same key_2 and has any key_3 values as the record I modified. After the modification I'd just bubble sort the modified first row to it's place instead of using a time consuming query.

So basically a record looks like this:

```
create type t_num_tbl is table of number;

create type rec_type as object
(
 key_1 number,
 key_2 varchar2(30),
 key_3 t_num_tbl     
);
```

and the collection is like this:

```
create type rec_typetbl is table of rec_type;

v_rectbl rec_typetbl := rec_typetbl();
```

If I modify a record I'd have to give out a select/update that looks something like this to be able to modify the associated records:

```
SELECT *
FROM table(v_rectbl)t
WHERE t.key_2 = modifiedrec.key_2
  AND
    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM table(t.key_3)
     JOIN table(modifiedrec.key_3) USING (column_value)) > 1;
```

The main problem here is that the data is not indexed in the memory and the access is just not fast enough for my purpose.

Are there any solutions in PLSQL that could compare to the performance of using a pointer array in a record to the associated elements of the collection? The associations are known beforehand since key_2, key_3 values don't change.

Comment: Perhaps it is an overkill for your application but check Oracle [TimesTen In-Memory Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/timesten/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, I can recommend against your design and would rather see you use the RDBMS the way it is designed (i.e. indexed access).

Having said that, every Oracle table has a rownum pseudo column that is a pointer to a row (i.e. that's how indexes internally reference specific rows in a table).  If you have the record, you can save the rownum in your data structure to get back to it quickly (don't persist the rownum long term as oracle can change the rownum when tables/rows are re-organized).

Comment: Using "don't persist the rownum long term as oracle can change the rownum when tables/rows are re-organized" is a bit weak, better use `FOR UPDATE`, clauses when you work with ROWID's then such rows are locked.

Comment: The idea here is solid, but th wrong pseudo column. It's rowid that is associated to each row. Rownum is assigned to the row as it is selected for processing. It is possible for different runs of the same query to return the exact same data but each row having a different rownum.

Comment: thanks @WernfriedDomscheit for your thoughts/corrections.